What is the purpose of this zig-zagged wire going between bolts on a plate on a concrete bridge support?
I was walking under a raised highway in Shibuya, and noticed these plates on some of the bridge supports.
They are flat metal plates with arrays of bolts. Some of the plates just have the bolts, but some of them have a wire zig-zagging through the groups of the bolts.
It can be seen here in Google Streetview (screenshot added below for convenience):
https://www.google.com/maps/@35.6544957,139.6940495,3a,20.5y,348.38h,130.11t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s1wselYCaNSGAXpi0WvguOA!2e0!7i16384!8i8192?coh=205409&entry=ttu&g_ep=EgoyMDI0MDkwMy4wIKXMDSoASAFQAw%3D%3D

I have no structural engineering / civil engineering training, but I assume it couldn't serve a structural purpose because it's too small, and not applied to all of the bolts.
So, what is its purpose?
Because this is a bridge in earthquake-prone Tokyo, I assume there may be extra precautions taken to protect and diagnose structural issues. Is this some kind of strain or fracture sensor? Some kind of cathodic corrosion prevention system?

how do you know that it is a wire?

Visually, it is a metal wire/cable -- I don't necessarily mean wire in the "electrical wire" sense. It's just my best guess, because I can't see how it could have a structural role.

they look more like a spacers ... maybe they are retainers that prevent the nuts from turning on their own ... or part of protective caps placed on the nuts

In line with traffic movement, while other side has none.  Counter vibration.

This looks like safety retaining wire. see here
Here is an image

Used to stop bolts from unfastening due to vibration.
